# Tiles not getting disposed when going off-screen

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, gridview, staggered-gridview

I am working on a video conferencing app and displaying 4 video tiles in a view using Staggered Grid View package.For video rendering I am using native surface renderers but I am facing a problem that when certain tiles goes off screen they are not getting disposed and still the video stays on for off-screen tiles causing performance overhead.I want that whenever the tile goes off-screen the video should turn off automatically.Is there any way in which I can optimize other than visibilityDetector package.

```
MasonryGridView.count(
 cacheExtent: 0,
 addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
 scrollDirection:
 Axis.horizontal,
 physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
 itemCount: data.item3,
 crossAxisCount: 2,
 itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
    return VideoTile();//Video Rendering Widget
 },
);
```

Comment: have you tried your video controller dispose if not please share your details code snippet to understand your problem more specific.

Comment: Thanks @SaifulIslam please find the code here : https://github.com/100mslive/100ms-flutter/blob/final-provider-implmentation/example/lib/meeting/meeting_page.dart

Comment: The controller from native side automatically gets called when the video widget gets disposed from flutter side.